# Using MongoDB locally (electron)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, electron

I need to store some data as part of my electron application. I know how to set up a REST API, and serve my application like so. However, is it also possible to use (e.g.) MongoDB locally, and implement something similar to a REST API locally? I would like to not assume an internet connection for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you have nodejs in electron so you can use mongoose:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose

But in this case every person who use your application have to install mongodb in his machine.

Comment: oh, so this is a clear disadvantage then. I cannot just 'pre-ship' mongodb with my software (as in: it being included / the user not having to deal with this), but the user would have to explicitly install it? : /

Comment: yes it is. If you just want a mongodb like database, you can try the solution of Dani Akash. But if you really want mongodb, the user had to install it himself or you have to create an installation script for your app.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to implement a mongoDB like database locally for the application without internet, you can use [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb)

Comment: is there advantage over mongodb? would the user have to install this database him or herself, or could I just include it in my application?

Comment: unlike mongodb, lowdb is not a standalone application it's a js plugin. You can include it in your project just like any other js plugin and the user can use it without worries :)